# How to start fragment from PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, adapter, fragmentpageradapter

I want to start Fragment in my custom pager adapter. However, I do not know how to get the `getSupportFragmentManager()` to begin the transaction.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

This is my code, custom adapter for Pager:

```
public static class SlideShowAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private ArrayList<Movie> popularMovieList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public SlideShowAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> popularMovieList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.popularMovieList =popularMovieList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return popularMovieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
        View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, view, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.slideShowImg);
        Picasso.with(context).load(popularMovieList.get(position).getImage()).into(myImage);
        view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MovieFragment movieFragment = MovieFragment
                        .newInstance(popularMovieList.get(position),popularMovieList.get(position).getGenre());
                /***These code below does not work*/
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragArea,movieFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        return myImageLayout;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `FragmentManager` in `SlideShowAdapter`:

- One approach is to pass its instance to `SlideShowAdapter` constructor
- Another one is to pass your `Activity` as `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` (`Activity` class does not have `getSupportFragmentManager()` method) to its constructor and then do `myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I tried the second approach, and it is correct. However, it did not go to fragment when I clicked the item

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution based on @Amin Mousavi suggestion.

```
public static class SlideShowAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private ArrayList<Movie> popularMovieList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private FragmentActivity context;

    public SlideShowAdapter(FragmentActivity context, ArrayList<Movie> popularMovieList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.popularMovieList =popularMovieList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return popularMovieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
        View myImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, view, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) myImageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.slideShowImg);
        Picasso.with(context).load(popularMovieList.get(position).getImage()).into(myImage);
        view.addView(myImageLayout, 0);
        myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MovieFragment movieFragment = MovieFragment
                        .newInstance(popularMovieList.get(position),popularMovieList.get(position).getGenre());
                /***These code below does not work*/
                context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragArea,movieFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

            }
        });
        return myImageLayout;
    }
```